# Vue list component doesn't render object attributes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have 2 components in vue 3; the first is FilmComp.vue that represent a single film (a card div with some attributes) and a ListFilms.vue that represent a list of Film component rendered with a `v-for` but FilmComp.vue doesn't see the film object attributes.

FilmComp.vue :

```
<template>
  <div
    class="relative flex w-96 flex-col rounded-xl bg-white bg-clip-border text-gray-700 shadow-md"
  >
    <div
      class="relative mx-4 mt-4 h-80 overflow-hidden rounded-xl bg-white bg-clip-border text-gray-700 shadow-lg"
    >
      <img :src="film.imgSrc" alt="profile-picture" />
    </div>
    <div class="p-6 text-center">
      <h4
        class="mb-2 block font-sans text-2xl font-semibold leading-snug tracking-normal text-blue-gray-900 antialiased"
      >
        {{ film.title }}
      </h4>
      <p
        class="block bg-gradient-to-tr from-pink-600 to-pink-400 bg-clip-text font-sans text-base font-medium leading-relaxed text-transparent antialiased"
      >
        {{ film.genre }}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex justify-center gap-7 p-6 pt-2">
      {{ film.year }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const film = defineProps({
  film: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
})
</script>
```

ListFilms.vue :

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-white">
    <div class="mx-auto max-w-2xl px-4 py-16 sm:px-6 sm:py-24 lg:max-w-7xl lg:px-8">
      <div class="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-10 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:gap-x-8">
        <div v-for="film in films" :key="film.id" class="group relative">
          <FilmComp :film="film" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import FilmComp from './FilmComp.vue'

const films = ref([
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
    year: 1994,
    genre: 'drama',
    imgSrc: 'aaaaaaaaa'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'The Godfather',
    year: 1972,
    genre: 'drama',
    imgSrc: 'aaaaaaaaa0'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'The Godfather: Part II',
    year: 1974,
    genre: 'drama',
    imgSrc: 'aaaaaaaaa1'
  }
])
</script>
```

The ListFilms component should be see film property object for actuate datbiding in html ({{ -- }} syntax).

Comment: Try removing the `const film = ` before `defineProps`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declared a variable named `film`. You said that the value of this variable should be all the properties of the element. One of the properties is `film`.

So, you can access the properties from the const object `film`. One of the properties is named `film`. So, in your case, extracting the `film` property would be `film.film`.
**This is a "logical error".**

**Generally, we name properties as `props` in about 99% of cases.**

```js
const props = defineProps({ ... });
```

In this case, I can access all the properties of the element through the const variable `props`. If I declare a property named `film`, I will access it as `props.film`.

#### Solution

```js
const props = defineProps({
  film: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
})
```

In this way, in the template section, you no longer need to refer explicitly to `props` since Vue automatically detects it when you want to extract a property from the props object.

In this case, within the `<script>` section, you can access the properties through the props variable.

```js
console.log(props.film)
```

In the `<template>` section, you should reference it without using the "props" keyword, similar to the "Options API". It is crucial not to declare a variable with the same name as the property in the `<script>` section! So, in this case, there should not be something like `const film = 'test'` or similar declarations...

```
{{ film }}
```

[Vue Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

#### Is the `const props` necessary?

If you don't want to reference any of the properties within the `<script>` section, then it's not necessary.

##### (Working) Without `const props` (using only `<template>`)

```html
<!-- WORKING -->

<template>
  <div>{{ film }}</div> <!-- WORKING -->
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({
  film: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
})
</script>
```

##### (Working) With `const props` (using only `<template>`)

```html
<!-- WORKING -->

<template>
  <div>{{ film }}</div> <!-- WORKING -->
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  film: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
})
</script>
```

However, if you want to reference them somewhere, then declaring the `const props` is needed, as it allows you to reuse the properties in the `<script>`. I recommend always declaring it as `const props` and keeping the variable name `props` reserved for this purpose, to maintain clear and organized code.

##### (Wrong) Without `const props`

```html
<!-- ERROR -->

<template>
  <div>{{ film }}</div> <!-- WORKING -->
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({
  film: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
})

console.log(film) // ERROR: film is not defined
</script>
```

##### (Working) With `const props`

```html
<!-- WORKING -->

<template>
  <div>{{ film }}</div> <!-- WORKING -->
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  film: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
})

console.log(props.film) // WORKING
</script>
```

#### More information

- [Props Declaration](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props-declaration) - Vue Docs
- [`defineProps()`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits) - Vue Docs

Comment: For completeness, if you want, there's also `toRefs()` + destructuring, and the `$props` meta variable. To add to your list :)

Comment: You are absolutely right! Although the solutions described here currently solve the problem and provide a broader insight into understanding the operating principle.

Comment: From my perspective, we are solely talking about a logical error here, which the questioner committed because they do not really know or grasp what is being achieved behind the background of defining the props.

Comment: Agreed, the main issue here is a misunderstanding of props (and `defineProps` in particular) work. I was referring to those methods for completeness, and because they are common practices, with `toRefs()` being very useful in larger components. They also provide much better editor integration, AFAIK. But have my upvote anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining props but trying to use the resulting props object as a single prop; `defineProps()` returns a reactive object with the props as properties.
Because of the name you used (the same as the prop), it shadowed the actual prop and you ended up trying to access nonexistent props.

You should change

```js
const film = defineProps({
  // ...
})
```

to

```js
const props = defineProps({
  // ...
})
```

or

```js
defineProps({
  // ...
})
```

---

**In the template,** you can use props directly; you don't have to use the props object. You don't even need to assign it, as shown in the third code block above.

However, I consider this an anti-pattern, as it obscures the source of the data and allows the name to be shadowed with any warnings being raised (as in your case).
Accessing them on the props object or clearly defining them with `toRefs()` avoids these issues.

A better method for this approach is to use the `$props` object (template-only "meta variable").
This also solves the aforementioned issues, but without any extra overhead in the script.

---

If you want, you can use the common pattern of destructuring the props object:

```js
const props = defineProps({
  film: {
    type: Object,
    required: true
  }
})

const { film } = toRefs(props)
```

This uses the `toRefs()` helper to extract the `film` prop as a ref.

It allows use **in the script** to access props directly, instead of having to reference them on the props object.
It also clearly defines a name for the prop, which allows direct use in the template while still avoiding the possibility of name shadowing.

Comment: Vue does that automatically, you don't need the `toRefs`. They simply need to remove the `const film =` and the `film` prop will be accessible in the template.

Comment: I had an edit on the way, but was busy. I have added in the various methods.

Comment: @paddyfields Is my answer clearer now?

Comment: @paddyfields If there's anything amiss or that could be improved, please let me know (or edit and correct/expand the answer yourself :) )