# unable to set property disable to a button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

as shown in the below posted code, i am developing a child-component, in it i created a button and i want to add `disable` property.
given the code below, the `disable` property is underlined with red color and the error message says:

```
Type '"isDigitizePolygonDisabled"' is not assignable to type 'Booleanish | undefined'
```

please let me know how to set `disable` property correctly
**code**:

```
<template>
<button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="digitizePolygonBtn" disabled='isDigitizePolygonDisabled'>
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

let isDigitizePolygonDisabled = ref(true)
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isDigitizePolygonDisabled
        }
    },
    props: {
        isDigitizePolygonDisabled: { 
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
    },
}
</script>
```

**update**:

```
when i use the code posted below, vs-code underlines `isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled` and gives an error messages says:

`duplicate key isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled`

how to solve it please
<template>
<button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="clsDigitizePolygonBtn" :disabled="isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled">
    <slot></slot>
</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    setup(props) {
       return {
        isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled: props.isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled,
    } 
    },
    props: {
        isDigitizePolygonBtnDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            default: false,
        },
    },
});
</script>
```

Comment: Remove second variable declaration from setup()'s return. First, you declared propery on props. Then you declared variable eith same name on setup(). Dont need variable with same() name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved it as shown below.

**parent**

```
<template>
    <ButtonDigitizePolygon @click="onDigitizePolygon()" :isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled=isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled>
        <template v-slot:slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel>
            {{ compPropsIsToggleBtnDigitizePolygon }}
        </template>
    </ButtonDigitizePolygon>
</template>

<script>
    let isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled = ref(false);
    ...
    ...
    ...
<script>
```

**child component**

```
<template>
<button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="clsDigitizePolygonBtn" :disabled="isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled">
    <slot name="slotDigitizePolygonBtnLabel"></slot>
</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    date() {
        return {
            btnDigitizePolyhonState: this.isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled,
        };
    },
    props: {
        isBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the error, You're passing `isDigitizePolygonDisabled` variable as a string but ideally it should be `boolean`. To fix this, you should bind the attribute using the `:disabled` directive.

Try this way **:**

```
<button
  id="idDigitizePolygonBtn"
  class="digitizePolygonBtn"
  :disabled="isDigitizePolygonDisabled"
>
  <slot></slot>
</button>
```

In Script **:**

```
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    isDigitizePolygonDisabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, when you want to bind a boolean attribute like disabled, you can use the v-bind directive (or its shorthand `:`). This binds an attribute to an expression.

If you try to bind the disabled attribute the way you're doing it, Vue thinks you're trying to set the string 'isDigitizePolygonDisabled' as the value for disabled, which is invalid. Hence, the error you're seeing.

So, final code will be:

```
<template>
  <button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="digitizePolygonBtn" :disabled="isButtonDisabled">
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        isDigitizePolygonDisabled: { 
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        },
    },
    setup(props) {
        
        // For now, just return the prop
        return {
            isButtonDisabled: props.isDigitizePolygonDisabled
        }
    }
})
</script>
```

I preferred to use `defineComponent` and `setup` which I think are more straight forward to use.

Comment: thanks, i would like to know, would there be any difference if the code i provided is a for a child or pareant?i mean the code i posted it for a child component. would there be any difference if it was for a parent component. also, i am using `optionsAPI` thus, i can not use `defineComponent`, right?

Comment: @Amrmsmb with options API, you can use `defineComponent`. I am using it in my project.

Comment: When using TypeScript, as evident from your question, it's necessary to use the [defineComponent()](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#definecomponent) function as well.

Comment: would you please have a look at the update section i added to the question?!

Comment: Options API can use prop without variable declaration. Now, variable how updated when property updated?

Comment: Follow documentation: [TypeScript with Options API](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#typing-component-props) - Vue Docs

Answer (score 0):

#### Summary

I had to cover a lot in the response - imports, variable passing, slot/template usage - so I've gathered the essential parts at the top.

###### How to give another type value

- `<button disabled="false">` --- string type value: `"false"`
- `<button :disabled="false">` --- boolean type value: `false`
- `<button testProp="123">` --- string type value: `"123"`
- `<button :testProp="123">` --- number type value: `123`
- `<button testProp="text">` --- string type value: `"text"`
- `<button :testProp="'text'">` --- string type value: `"text"`
- `<button testProp="[1, 2, 3]">` --- string type value: `"[1, 2, 3]"`
- `<button :testProp="[1, 2, 3]">` --- array type value: `[1, 2, 3]`

  Has variable as `const isDisabled = false;`, then:
- `<button disabled="isDisabled">` --- string type value: `"isDisabled"`
- `<button :disabled="isDisabled">` --- boolean type (by `isDisabled` variable) value: `false`

If we want to pass a variable or a non-string value to an attribute - currently, we want to pass a boolean type - then in every case, a colon must be placed before the variable. This way, the type of the passed value remains unchanged.

###### How to give prop to children element

- `<ChildrenElement propertyName="propertyValue" />`

The use of a colon is applicable in the previous type passing scenario... In the example, I passed the text `propertyValue` as a string to the prop named `propertyName`. Naturally, proper importing of `ChildrenElement` and defining the props within it is essential (as later described).

###### How to use `<slot>` and `<template>`

Using , you generate a template whose HTML code can be overridden after importing the child element. This is employed when creating a universal component where it's possible that individual elements need to be utilized differently.

---

#### Solution # 1, declare as `property`

- [Vue `props` declaration](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#props-declaration) - Vue Docs

###### Options API

The use of `defineComponent()` is necessary in the Options API only when using TypeScript.

- [When need `defineComponent()` using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66957139/15167500) - StackOverflow Answer

In the Options API, you can define your component's properties in the `props` attribute, the value of which you'll need to pass when declaring the component. You can pre-set the property's data type, in this case, `boolean`. You can provide a default value, as in my example, `true`, or you can decide to make the variable mandatory, in which case specifying a default value is not significant. For the sake of quickly illustrating my example, I had to work with a default value.

###### ChildrenButton.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="digitizePolygonBtn" :disabled='isDigitizePolygonDisabled'>
      Test Button
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue' // need with TypeScript using

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    isDigitizePolygonDisabled: { 
      type: Boolean,
      default: true, // when not required, will can declare default value
      // required: true, // if need required property
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  props: {
    isDigitizePolygonDisabled: { 
      type: Boolean,
      default: true, // when not required, will can declare default value
      // required: true, // if need required property
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="digitizePolygonBtn" :disabled='isDigitizePolygonDisabled'>
    Test Button
  </button>
</div>
```

###### How to import Children Component to Parent Element (Options API)

- [Component Local Registration](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration) - Vue Docs

If the component containing the button is named `ChildrenButton`, then the declaration within the parent element would look like this:

###### ParentElement.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ChildrenButton :isDigitizePolygonDisabled="false" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue' // need with TypeScript using
import ChildrenButton from './path/to/ChildrenButton.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    ChildrenButton, // now can use this component on <template>
  }
})
</script>
```

###### Composition API

In the Composition API, the `defineProps()` function can be used to define properties. Its structure is similar to the example from the previous Options API.

- [How to use `defineProps()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76812673/15167500) - StackOverflow Answer
- [`defineProps()`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits) - Vue Docs

###### ChildrenButton.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="digitizePolygonBtn" :disabled='isDigitizePolygonDisabled'>
      Test Button
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
// need use defineProps
const props = defineProps({
  isDigitizePolygonDisabled: { 
    type: Boolean,
    default: true, // when not required, will can declare default value
    // required: true, // if need required property
  }
})
</script>
```

```js
const { createApp, defineProps } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    // need use defineProps
    const props = defineProps({
     isDigitizePolygonDisabled: { 
        type: Boolean,
        default: true, // when not required, will can declare default value
        // required: true, // if need required property
      }
    })
    
    return { props }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="digitizePolygonBtn" :disabled='isDigitizePolygonDisabled'>
    Test Button
  </button>
</div>
```

###### How to import Children Component to Parent Element (Composition API)

- [Component Local Registration](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration) - Vue Docs

If the component containing the button is named `ChildrenButton`, then the declaration within the parent element would look like this:

###### ParentElement.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <ChildrenButton :isDigitizePolygonDisabled="false" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import ChildrenButton from './path/to/ChildrenButton.vue' // now can use this component on <template>
</script>
```

---

#### Solution # 2, declare as `reactive variable`

Instead of setting a `property`, you also have the option to declare a fixed `reactive variable`. In this case, the variable's value cannot be directly assigned from outside.

###### Options API

In the case of the Options API, you can declare such variables within the `data()` property.

- [`data()`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#data) - Vue Docs

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      isDigitizePolygonDisabled: true, // declare reactive variable with default variable (not property)
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="digitizePolygonBtn" :disabled='isDigitizePolygonDisabled'>
    Test Button
  </button>
</div>
```

###### Composition API

In the Composition API, you have access to the `reactive()` and `ref()` functions. The provided descriptions demonstrate their functionalities well.

- [`ref()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) - Vue Docs (reactive core)
- [`reactive()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive) - Vue Docs (reactive core)

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const isDigitizePolygonDisabled = ref(true) // declare reactive variable with default variable (not property)
    
    return { isDigitizePolygonDisabled }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="digitizePolygonBtn" :disabled='isDigitizePolygonDisabled'>
    Test Button
  </button>
</div>
```

---

#### `slot` and `template` on Vue

Since you want to use `<slot>` in your question, I'll provide an example of how you can properly use it within a child-parent component relationship.

I've already discussed the differences in imports above, and the usage of `<slot>` and `<template>` remains the same in both Options API and Composition API. The example provided was done using the Options API.

- [How to use `<slot>`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#slot-content-and-outlet) - Vue Docs

Multiple `<slot>`s can be placed within a single component. `<slot>`s can be given names. When declaring multiple `<slot>`s, it is mandatory to differentiate them. You will find an example of this in the attached documentation. When declaring in the parent element, the value of a  can be overwritten using a `<template>`. An unnamed `<slot>` can be referenced using an unnamed `<template>`, but its default name is `default`. If you rename a `<slot>`, you need to specify the name of the `<slot>` you want to override in the `<template>`. You can override multiple `<slot>`s simultaneously, as demonstrated in this example.

###### ChildrenButton.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button id="idDigitizePolygonBtn" class="digitizePolygonBtn" :disabled='isDigitizePolygonDisabled'>
      <slot>
        <strong>Default HTML code here!</strong> <!-- If you don't declare a <template>, the content of the <slot> will appear by default. If a <template> is declared, it overrides the value of the <slot>. -->
      </slot>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue' // need with TypeScript using

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    isDigitizePolygonDisabled: { 
      type: Boolean,
      default: true, // when not required, will can declare default value
      // required: true, // if need required property
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

###### ParentElement.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- 1. Without <template>, now will appear content of <slot> -->
    <ChildrenButton :isDigitizePolygonDisabled="false" />

    <!-- 2. With <template>, now will appear content of current element's <template> -->
    <ChildrenButton :isDigitizePolygonDisabled="false">
      <template>New unqiue HTML code here</template>
    </ChildrenButton>

    <!-- 3. With <template>, now will appear content of current element's <template> (just another content) -->
    <ChildrenButton :isDigitizePolygonDisabled="false">
      <template>
        <span style="color: red;">New unqiue HTML code here</span>
      </template>
    </ChildrenButton>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue' // need with TypeScript using
import ChildrenButton from './path/to/ChildrenButton.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    ChildrenButton, // now can use this component on <template>
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: as the code you provided is for a child component, would you please show me how the parent component will look like when using the child component is it?

Comment: @Amrmsmb I have updated my response. I primarily focused on the use of `props`, briefly mentioning the use of `data` or `ref`/`reactive` as alternative options. **With regards to `props`, I presented both the template structure of a child and a parent element. I hope I have managed to convey everything clearly.** I also searched through my previous responses for related topics, so it might be worth reviewing them.

Comment: The use of defineComponent() is necessary in the Options API only when using TypeScript. If you prefer not to use defineComponent(), then avoiding the use of TypeScript is required. (Since you also used TypeScript in your question, I addressed that aspect as well.)

Comment: would you please have a look at the update section i added to the question?!

Comment: If you declared props on Options API, dont need declare as variable on setup(), just use variable on template without this., or call variable on methods with this.. Prop declared equal to variable declare, and can use property as variable. Follow my example: Solution # 1 Options API

Comment: If property is required then dont need to default value.

Comment: but how can i specify the initial value without setting `default` value please?

Comment: When you call this component on another component, you need to set property. Sometimes use variable on parent element to can set dynamic property. If you dont need property, can use local variable as my Solution # 2 Options API. When use property than you need set default value on parent element as you can see in my examples.